# I have a txt file(university_towns.txt) containing names for university towns and the stat it belonging to. I want to read this using pandas

Tags: python, data-cleaning

*Desicribe: in this txt file, the state names is ending by [edit]. And items between two [edit]s are names of university towns. I need to read the whole txt file into a pd.Dataframe with two columns named 'State' and 'RegionName'. However, the difficult thing is that the txt file have each item in a row, if I use df=pd.read_table('university_towns.txt') directly, the Dataframe would be with only one column and put both state-names and region names in this columns. How can I deal with this?

Thanks in advance!*

**Part of my txt**

"Alabama[edit]

Auburn (Auburn University)[1]

Florence (University of North Alabama)

Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]

Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]

Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]

Troy (Troy University)[2]

Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]

Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]

Alaska[edit]

Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]

Arizona[edit]

Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]

Tempe (Arizona State University)

Tucson (University of Arizona)

Arkansas[edit]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('Universities.txt', 'r') as f:

    #Read non-empty lines:
    data = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = list(line for line in data if line)

    #Get the index of states:
    r_idx = [lines.index(line) for line in lines if '[edit]' in line]

    #Separating states and university names using wrapping indexes:
    university = []
    region = [lines[i].replace('[edit]', '') for i in r_idx]
    for i in range(len(r_idx)):
        if i != len(r_idx)-1:
            sub = lines[r_idx[i]+1:r_idx[i+1]]
            university.append(sub)
        else:
            sub = lines[r_idx[i]+1:]
            university.append(sub)


    #Create dict:
    uni = dict(zip(region, university))
```

Here I tried to extract info into separate lists then map them together. Some data formatting is on the fly also.

Does this help?

Comment: That's great. Thanks!